# how to draw graph using xml data in workfloweditor in mxgraph using javascript,php

Tags: javascript, php, mxgraph

How  to draw a graph in workfloweditor a sample which is provided with mxgraph(workfloweditor sample) using xml data. Is it possible to load data in xml? 
My XML STRING

```
var xml_string='
     <mxGraphModel>
        <root>
            <Workflow label="MyWorkflow" description="" href="" id="0">
                <mxCell />
            </Workflow>
            <Layer label="Default Layer" id="1">
                <mxCell parent="0" />
            </Layer>
            <Task label="Task" description="" href="" id="3">
                <mxCell vertex="1" parent="1">
                    <mxGeometry x="220" y="80" width="72" height="32" as="geometry" />
                </mxCell>
            </Task>
            <Edge label="" description="" id="5">
                <mxCell edge="1" parent="1" source="3" target="4">
                    <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry" />
                </mxCell>
            </Edge>
        </root>
    </mxGraphModel>';

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are asking for. If you want draw a graph loading an xml string you can use this code:

```
        var container = document.getElementById("your-div-element-id");;

    var xml = '<xml .....   />';
    var graph = new mxGraph(container);
    var diagram = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
    var codec = new mxCodec(diagram);
    codec.decode(diagram.documentElement, graph.getModel());
    graph.fit();
```

If I didn't catch your needs, please clarify it and let me know.
bye
Marco

Comment: HOw to read xml file instead from the folder of this var xml = '<xml .....   />';